# UTF/unicode parsing to readable format in Android

Tags: java, android, serialization

In JSON response from server, I am getting title (Language: Hindi) encoded like this:

```
à¤µà¥‡à¤¤à¤¾à¤² à¤ªà¤šà¥à¤šà¥€à¤¸à¥€
```

How can I convert this into readable format?

This should translate to : `वेताल पच्चीसी`

This is [code](https://github.com/Claymus/claymus/blob/master/src/com/claymus/api/GenericApi.java) for server.

Here on `HttpServletResponse` character encoding is set to `UTF-8`

```
HttpServletResponse response

response.setCharacterEncoding( "UTF-8" );
```

Is the encoding culprit?
Can somebody suggest way to decode it in Java/Android?

Comment: Please provide more context. How are you retrieving the string? What do you *expect* it to contain?

Comment: is it some other language ?

Comment: Context: JSON responsew from server 
"title":"à¤µà¥‡à¤¤à¤¾à¤² à¤ªà¤šà¥à¤šà¥€à¤¸à¥€"

Language: Hindi

Comment: Which protocol is used to talk to the server? Does it send any metadata to describe the encoding, e.g. a `Content-Type` HTTP header?

Comment: This is response from server, no HTTP header :(
{  
         "title":"à¤µà¥‡à¤¤à¤¾à¤² à¤ªà¤šà¥à¤šà¥€à¤¸à¥€",
         "titleEn":"Baital Pachisi"
}

Comment: Will it make any difference, If I use GSON instead of JSON?

Comment: I can ask to modify server side code, please suggest ant recommendation.

Comment: Is setCharacterEncoding on server is culprit?

Comment: Please suggest some method to decode UTF-8 character encoding in Java